# Time Stamping on snaps

Tags: android

We are using android based mobile phone for taking snaps of utility meters like electricity and natural gas. We need to time stamp each snap as it is the essential requirement for the acceptance of the snaps by the government authority. Kindly indicate how can we time stamp snaps in android phone.

Comment: Something like `long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()` ? Your question isn't very clear

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** :

You can generate and save your timestamp, once you reach in **`onActivityResult()`** method after taking the snap, follow the steps.

**Step 1**: Fire the `Camera Intent`, so that `Camera Activity` can open.

**Step 2**: After the snap(image) has been captured, `OnActivityResult()` method will be called.

**Step 3**: Inside this method you can generate the **current timeStamp**, like this( snippet is in **Kotlin** ) :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 

      val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("your_desired_timestamp_pattern",Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date())
       saveCurrentTimeStamp(timeStamp)
 }
```

**Step 4**: Save this **timeStamp** in some persistence storage like your DataBase.

I would suggest saving the captured image(snaps) files itself with the name of timeStamp(the moment they were captured).

**Although this method doesn't provide the exact interval at which the snap were captured, the actual delay is just of some seconds .**

**Method 2** :

One other way is to implement a **`BroadCastReceiver`** for **`ACTION_NEW_PICTURE`** and then inside your `onReceive()` method you can save the timeStamp.

update - `ACTION_NEW_PICTURE` was deprecated in **Android N**, but later they brought it back in **Android O** but only for registered receivers.

Comment: Thank you very much I shall try both methods and let you know soon.